# Why are all values null after serializing the object list?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have tried to serialize the class which contains the list of objects but instead of creating the string with the appropriate values, the method `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` return the JSON string where all values in the list are null.

The line which should create the string from object is the following:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);
```

where msg is the class

```
public class JSONPlayerListResponse
{
    public List<Player> Players {get; set;}

    public MessageType Action
    {
        get { return MessageType.GetPlayerListResponse; }
    }

    public string CommID { get; set; }

    public string PlayerID { get; set; }
}
```

and Player is

```
[DataContract]
public class Player
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public decimal Ballance { get; set; }

    public System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<Bet> BetsHistory { get; set; }

    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

The list Players in msg instance contains one element, which value FName is set to Player1 but the return string is the following:

```
{\"Players\":[{\"UserName\":null,\"Password\":null,\"CurrencyCode\":null,\"CountryCode\":null,\"FName\":null,\"LName\":null}],\"Action\":18,\"CommID\":null,\"PlayerID\":\"27de1\"}
```

Does anyone know why all values in the returned string are null and how to modify the logic in order to generate string that contains actual values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't initialize `Players` with real values. `Players.Add(new Player())` isn't enough.

Try this.

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        new JSONPlayerListResponse() { 
            Players = new List<Player>() { new Player(){UserName="test name"} } 
        }
    );
```

You will see that UserName is not null.